# Microsoft Graph: avoid authorization each time I launch a process

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I would like to integrate the Planner feature of Teams into a custom C++/Qt application. I'm not familiar with writing bindings C# <-> C++, so I'm exploring the possibility to use an external process that communicates with Microsoft Graph. I'm going to build this process with the [C# Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

**Question**: Is it possibile to avoid authentication every time I launch the process? Since I'm going to spawn this process many times (ie. each time I need to access Graph info) I want to avoid authenticating each time.

I've tried using [Microsoft authentication extensions for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/tree/master/sample/ManualTestApp), and while the sample application seems to be working fine, I can't figure out how to connect it with the `GraphServiceClient` class.

```
// This is how the example set up the cache
// See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/sample/ManualTestApp/Program.cs#L32

            var pca =
                CreatePublicClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations");
            var cacheHelper =
                CreateCacheHelperAsync().Result;
            cacheHelper.RegisterCache(pca.UserTokenCache);

// This is how the GraphServiceClient is created in the tutorial
// See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core?tutorial-step=3

            tokenCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(callBack, clientId);
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(tokenCredential, scopes);
```

I'm using the DeviceCode authentication flow because I understand it's the right thing to do for desktop application, but I'm available to change method.

The final application will be deployed on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly what I need in this repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-desktop-tutorial/tree/master/2-TokenCache

I needed to make some adjustments to compile it for .NET Core, but the code works flawlessy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).